# DataGridView com DataSet Valor Personalizado

Tags: c#, postgresql, datagridview, integração, npgsql

Olá, bom dia.
Gostaria de pedir uma ajuda a vocês sobre a seguinte situação:

Uso o banco de dados PostgreSQL integrado ao Visual Studio Enterprise com o pacote **(Npgsql PostgreSQL Integration)**. Para aqueles que ainda não sabem este pacote permite que você gerencie o BD direto do VS igualmente ao SQL Server.

Mas enfim, até hoje eu não tive problemas com isso pois só usava para preencher uma `DataGridView` com o que eu tenho no Banco.

Automaticamente ele gera o código:

```
this.backlogTableAdapter.Fill(this.dsGestorSQL.backlog);
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente para mostrar os dados do Banco, mas preciso usar uma coluna do tipo `DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn` e como disse a cima ele gera um código automaticamente que preenche o `DataGridView` teria uma possibilidade de usar esse método junto a uma validação:

```
if(ValueColumn == "S")
{
    MarcarCheckBox(Exemplo);
} 
else
{
    CheckBoxVazio(Exemplo);
}
```

Alguem sabe me informar de existe essa possibilidade?

Agradeço pela atenção e pela ajuda!

Comment: Se o `DataGridView` é preenchido automaticamente uma coluna do tipo `bool` não terá logo a `CheckBox` preenchida com o valor correto?

Comment: É, mas pelo visto é uma string "S"/"N"

Comment: estamos falando de WebForms?

Comment: Se for como o @LeandroAngelo refere, então essa alteração poderia ser feita do lado do SQL.

Comment: Olá amigos, obrigado por tentarem ajudar, a aplicação é em Windows Forms e a solução para este problema foi trazer do banco os valores "true" e "false" em uma coluna do tipo "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn" assim ele ler o valor do banco e preenche a check box caso estiver como "true".   

Espero que minha resposta também possa ajudar mais pessoas com essa duvida

Answer (score 0):

obrigado por tentarem ajudar, a aplicação é em Windows Forms e a solução para este problema foi trazer do banco os valores "true" e "false" em uma coluna do tipo "DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn" assim ele ler o valor do banco e preenche a check box caso estiver como "true". Espero que minha resposta também possa ajudar mais pessoas com essa duvida!